# WIll aluminium foil get hot in microoven if I wrap it with paper?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

A aluminium foil doesn't get hot easily because of it's heat conductivity. Will it get hot in microwave oven if I wrap it with paper?

Comment: Aluminum foil heats up quite easily. I think that what you mean is that aluminum foil from, say, a conventional oven doesn't retain heat well because it has such a large surface area for its mass.

Comment: Large metal objects reflect microwaves, so they don't heat fast. However, a narrow strip of foil can get very hot very fast (in my experience - maybe someone can explain the physics). Wrapping it in paper might start a fire.